# MySQL: is any way to SELECT data from locked table by ignoring that lock

Tags: mysql

session 1:

```
LOCK TABLES `table` WRITE;
DO SLEEP(10); //in real here set of INSERT UPDATE queries with the `table`
SELECT UNLOCK TABLES;
```

session 2:

```
SELECT id FROM `table`;
```

So Session 2 will wait 10 sec untill `table` became unlocked
I need to select without any waiting because at that time does not matter is data actualized or not.
The solution could be create `table_slave` to copy `table` sometimes and use it, but it looks not good.

Right now I'm using MySQL 5.7 but moving to 8.0 soon if it does matter.

Comment: In general no-access by other session makes sense. Maybe in session 1 you could make the table available as a quasi-copy/view (as you said). Maybe something like a table dump is still possible. Probably best is to lock as little as possible and do reentrable/repeatable partial changes. With some extra administrative table.

Comment: No you cannot, as that is what the lock is supposed to do. The question is: why do you use lock tables there? There may be other and better ways to do what you want to achieve with this lock, and you may need to elaborate what you want to achieve with this lock exactly and why "normal" transactions do not suffice.

Comment: Investigate 'MySql nowait' as an internet search. It will help you to decide what you want to happen on the second connection. You may decide to change the locking mode on the 'write' connection to allow reading while it is updating. This can be a 'rabbit hole' of trusting the information you get back. I suggest you don't go there. ;-/

Comment: I’ve tried both 'MySql nowait' by change session variables READ UNCOMMITTED and lock write / read. No result. Until now lock table was a perfect solution for whole project for few years. But now i need just one small and fast query...